# The display function doesn't execute , the head value keeps getting set to null so the display function keeps printing empty

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node *create(int num);
void display(void);
```

//linked list node creation

```
struct node
            {
            int data ;
            struct node  *next;
            };

        struct node *head = NULL;
        struct node *newnode;
        struct node *temp;


int main()

{   
    int num;

    printf("enter no of nodes\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(int i = 1 ;i<=num;i++)
    {enter code here
        create(num);
    }

    display();

    return 0 ;
}
```

// this executes properly

```
struct node *create(int num)
{   

        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));

        printf("enter data\n");
        scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
        newnode->next= NULL;

        if(head == 0)
        {
            head=newnode=temp;
        }

        else
        {
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp= newnode;
        }
        return head;

}


void display() 
{

            struct node *temp = head;
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                printf("empty\n");  
            }
```

// the create function works properly but the head keeps getting set to null

//doesn't execute this loop even if the linked list is not empty

```
else 
            {
                while(temp != NULL)
                    {
                         printf("%d-->",temp->data);
                        temp= temp->next;
                    }
            }


            return;
}
```

Do I need to create a temporary variable everytime I declare a function? Why are the global variables not working? If someone can point out the exact mistake please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: walk this code with a debugger! what does this do;  head=newnode=temp; ?

Comment: it assigns the head value as the value of the address of the new node and assigns the same to temp, if the head is NULL for the first created node

Comment: no it doesn't. run with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code was correct. This line was causing issue `head=newnode=temp;` It should be like shown in snippet below. Because instead of assigning your newly created node's address to **head** and **temp** you were assigning **temp**'s initial address.

```
if(head == 0)
{
     head=temp=newnode;
}
```